# Ubuntu 15.04 Can't pair apple bluetooth keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard, bluetooth, apple

I can't get my Apple Bluetooth keyboard to pair with Ubuntu 15.04. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

```
user:~$ sudo rfkill list
[sudo] password for rufus: 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05b8:3166 Agiler, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:2006 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

~$ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.184510] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.750612] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x381f00)
[   16.149672] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   16.149694] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.149698] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.149701] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.149713] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.241157] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd failed with error -2
[   16.241162] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd not found
[   31.184856] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   31.184859] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   31.184864] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   31.189160] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   31.189167] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   31.189171] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   33.525569] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will start by getting the firmware

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbmm9vfg2fby2zn/fw-04ca_2006.hcd
sudo cp fw-04ca_2006.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Then see if you can pair, if it doesn't pair edit question to include `dmesg | tail` from after the pairing attempt

Comment: Oh, thank you man! I've wasted a lot of time trying to connect my keyboard with 15.10 ubuntu device!

Answer (score 1):

This can be very frustrating, I had this problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and Apple Wireless Keyboard A1314 and got it working by trying with bluetoothctl with instructions from this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1490347
following:

`- agent on
- default-agent
- scan on // copy the device hardware address
- pair <replace-with-hw-address>
PIN code: #### <- type this on the apple keyboard
Enter PIN Code: #### <- type this on the apple keyboard
Pair successful..!`

quit

After successful pairing the num lock is on you need to press Fn+F6 to disable it.